# Resize data points with highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

We are using [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com) and are trying to customize a chart to look similar to this:
[image]

We were able to set colors as documented and also increase the thickness of the lines by using the `lineWidth` attribute, but can't find a way to customize the data points so they are always circles and larger than the thicker lines. This is what it looks like at this point:
[image]

Also, we can't find a way to remove the default gray horizontal lines.

Help!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This gray line is called grid line, you can customize them following the [reference](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/ref/#yAxis--gridLineWidth).

**To remove grid lines**

```
 yAxis: {
     gridLineWidth: 0
 }
```

Like this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/M7GhX/).

**Change marker width**

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        marker: {
            enabled: true,
            symbol: 'circle',
            radius: 7
        }
    }
}
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jQ28r/2/)

You can take a look [here](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/ref/#point-marker) if you want to customize series markers.

Comment: marker: {
                        symbol: 'url(/Content/images/highcharts/CandleStick/profit.png)',
                        width: 6,
                        height: 6,
                    } have no effect in highstock